# Multitheaded jersey client making HTTPS calls

Tags: java, https, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I am using latest version of javax.ws.rs.client.Client(Jersey client 2.34) to make multiple Https request using threads.

I am getting this exception when I am using multiple threads to make simultaneous calls using Jersey Client.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

It may seem like this exception is related to invalid certificate not present in the truststore. I have added the certificate for the site I am hitting to the truststore. Also, the code works fine if only single thread is used.

A simple version of my code looks like this:

```
.... // code that starts the threads.
for(int i=0;i<noOfThreads;i++){
   executorService.execute(new RunnableClient(url,jerseyClient));
}
....


class RunnableClient implements Runnable{
   ...
   @Override
   public void run(){
           jerseryClient.fetchResults(url);
   }
}


class JerseyClient{
   ...
   Client client;
   ...

   public Response fetchResults(String url){
         response = this.client.target(new URI(url)).request(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                            .header(Constants.AUTHORIZATION, getToken())
                            .get();
         return response;

}

....

// jerseyClient is the object of my user defined class which holds a javax.ws.rs.client.Client object as member.
```

It is to be noted that I am only making single instance of JerseyClient and reusing it.

But the code fails if more than one thread runs. Can anyone explain why this exception is raising and how to solve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does getToken() do? Jersey Client is thread safe however your wrapper might not be.

Comment: getToken() will get basic token for authorization header.
Well this problem is because of a bug in Jersey Client: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/issues/3396